# Identify if the request is initiated from Okta IDP (ASP .NET MVC App)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, okta, ws-federation

I have a .NET MVC App where I want to add OKTA as an IDP. I have used the WS-Fed Okta template to configure the App with Okta.
Here, we can either initiate the request from the SP or the IDP (Okta dashboard). Assuming that I send a request from Okta, is there any to programatically identify that the request has come from Okta Dashboard.
I am using WS-Federation protocol for authentication and WIF framework.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I suggest you to look into multitenant, finbuckle. Have a look into claims